# Realm Query possible to use IN?

Tags: android, realm

I have the following realm query but from reading the documentation I don't see a possibility to do an IN query.

I need to search for an id in a string or array containing that id. Is this possible?

Example code:

```
Realm realmThread = Realm.getInstance(visnetawrap.appModel);
RealmResults<PropertyObject> propResults = realmThread.where(PropertyObject.class).contains("propertyID", "(5,7,10)").findAll();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid I am pointing out the obvious, but you can chain `or`ed `equalTo`s.

```
RealmQuery<PropertyObject> query = realm.where(PropertyObject.class);
query.beginGroup();
for(int i = 0; i < propertyIDs.length - 1; i++) {
    query.equalTo("propertyID", propertyIDs[i]).or();
}

query.equalTo("propertyID", propertyIDs[propertyIDs.length - 1]).endGroup();
RealmResults<PropertyObject> propResults = query.findAll();
```

Comment: The `in` feature is already [requested](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/841). And one of the authors(?) suggests a similar workaround.